# Почему антивирус блокирует мою программу на другом устройстве?

Tags: python, безопасность, установка

Делаю программки на python. Из python файла конвентирую в exe. Потом через программу делаю для моей программы установщик. Скидываю ссылку на яндекс диск друзьям. После скачивания установщика Smart Screen выдаёт предупреждение о возможной опасности файла. Как это исправить и в чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что сам python не особо предназначен для компила в exe файлы, он вообще для этого не предназначен и использования спец утилит может вызвать подозрение со стороны антивирусов ибо "компайлер" может написать полный бред или подозрительные строки (Особенно если работа с реестром, драйверами. Вспомним тот же DriverPack)
Поэтому это нормально

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы Windows не сообщал о возможной опасности скачиваемого файла, нужно наличие сертификата проверенного издателя.
Вот дополнительная информация по этой теме:
https://habr.com/ru/company/tuthost/blog/152867/ и
https://habr.com/ru/amp/post/505194/
А вообще можно закинуть файлы программы в архив, на него действия Smart Screen не распространяются.

Comment: а ваша рекомендация точно применима к ситуации, описанной в вопросе?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, smart screen любит блокировать программы из интернета если у них нет цифровой подписи, либо если эту подпись видело мало пользователей.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я спрашивал про применимость метода покупки сертификата к тому, что у автора вопроса написано. а не про поведение всякого барахла, которое можно встретить в компьютерах у пользователей.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, подписанную программу антивирус будет считать более доверенной, чем неподписанную. В вопросе упоминается срабатывание антивируса. Smart screen - встроенная в винду штука, хотя антивирусом обычно называют не её, а windows defender (хотя думаю, smart screen тоже можно назвать антивирусом). Так что вполне связано с вопросом, тем более, ответил сам автор вопроса. А бесплатные сертификаты для подписи кода вроде бы не выдают?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в вопросе-то что написано? с помощью какой-то неупомянутой фигни скрипт обмазывается интерпретатором и засовывается внутрь (скорее всего) [pe](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). который с помощью другой неупомянутой фигни обмазывается ещё чем-то до состояния msi или чего-то в этом духе. // ввиду всех этих неоднозначностей совет просто купить сертификат выглядит слишком общей рекомендацией. думаю, какая-то конкретика тут не помешала бы.

Comment: Соглашусь, в моём вопросе и вправду есть неточность, я имел ввиду Smart Screen, а не какой-нибудь антивирус. А так наличие сертификата должно помочь для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: @PerL, наличие популярного сертификата. На единичные использования он будет продолжать ругаться.